# Clear interval function is not working in react native

Tags: react-native

```
  checkdrivercame(id) {
      var counttime = 0;

      this.intervalid=setInterval(() => {

          counttime++

          if (counttime > 5) {
              this.snackbarref.current.triggeranimate('Sorry!!, No cabs found in this location')
              this.setState({tooglebookstatus:true}, () => {
                  this.animbuttonref.current.stopanim()
                  this.animbuttonref.current.rerender()
                  clearInterval(this.intervalid)

              })

          }

      }, 5000);

  }
```

when calling `checkdrivercame()` the set interval is working fine but when `counttime` reaches 6  the if block also executes just fine but except `clearInterval`,

**Environment:**

```
 "react": "16.9.0",
    "react-native": "0.61.5",
```

I have been working in this issue for past two days, help me out, I have tried using `clearinterval` outside the scope even that is not working, but the timer keeps on looping.

Comment: does it execute for the 7th time too?

Comment: are there any errors in console ? try reproducing the error by creating a demo

Comment: executing also in 11 th time@GauravRoy

Comment: What kind of bugs you are expecting?@Allabakash